# How do I right align a ListBox?

Tags: google-apps-script

ListBox doesn't have a `setHorizontalAlignment` method and `setStyleAttribute("text-align", "right")` doesn't seem to be working.

How do I right align a ListBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `direction` to "rtl" may work. I'm not sure if that CSS attribute is whitelisted. Also, it may not have the appearance you're looking for despite the text being right-aligned.

Answer (score 1):

The setStyleAttribute method would be working if you would specify the attribute in camelCase as mentioned in the docs: [setStyleAttribute(attribute, value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/list-box#setStyleAttribute%28String,String%29)

attribute: the CSS attribute, **in camelCase.** ("fontSize", not "font-size").

`.setStyleAttribute("textAlign", "right")` should be o.k.

Comment: I don't think text-align works on `<select>`s (which is what a ListBox uses). Websites with custom dropdowns actually use other elements to simulate a `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

To align the listbox within a panel you would setHorizontalAlignment() on the panel like this:

```
panel.setHorizontalAlignment(UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT).add(ListBox);
```

Probably you want createHorizontalPanel(), see more about labels and panels in the [API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/horizontal-panel).

Answer (score -1):

You have to make right align using CSS. As in the following.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <div style="float:right;">     
               <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
           </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He's using the google-apps-script tag, so he's using a ASP ListBox.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say he's NOT using a ASP ListBox. My fingers don't always type what my brain thinks.